# http proxy for IIS shared hosting environment with management

Tags: iis, shared-hosting, http-proxy

In the [Microsoft ASP.NET 4 Hosting Deployment Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=fa53c2f0-7aca-407d-aeec-a738f56d01f2), it says that you should put a proxy server in place for hosted sites, and firewall all other requests in order to safely host and isolate applications.

It doesn't say what to use to do this. Ideally I'd like features where I could record things like amount of bandwidth used, throttle sites that are using too much etc.

Is there an open source or free proxy that one might typically use for this?

Answer (score 0):

A good open-source caching proxy is available here.

http://www.squid-cache.org/

I'd use SNORT or something for your IDS and IPTables as a firewall.

For forwarding proxy, you can certainly use Apache

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: It looks to me like Squid is a caching proxy - I need a forward proxy for monitoring and logging outgoing traffic

Comment: Ah - you can use Apache for that with the mod_proxy module. Added a link to their docs.